# How to add class to Angular's ngFor middle elements, or a default class

Tags: angular

I have Angular looping through some data, and I can add a class to the first and last items, but how can I add a class to all the others?

```
    <div *ngFor="let cat of item['catagory']; 
                 let first = first; 
                 let last = last" 
                 [class.article_cat_first]="first" 
                 [class.article_cat_last]="last">
         {{cat['title']}}
    </div>
```

Or, is it possible to add a default?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. It is generally smart enough to infer the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to other items with the condition `!first && !last`:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of item['catagory']; let first = first; let last = last" 
     [class.article_cat_others]="!first && !last" ... >
     ...
</div>
```

To set a default class, use the normal `class` attribute:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of item['catagory']; let first = first; let last = last" 
     class="defaultClass" ... >
     ...
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-hzk12d) for a demo.

Comment: Great, I like the "!first && !last"